# How to create a video quality controller like youtube in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how to create a video quality controller in flutter !!!

I have created a video player on top of [Chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie) & [video_player](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/video_player)

I have several questions like

- How to control the quality of the video like youtube (144p,240p,360p,480p and 720p),
- How to control the  resolution and bandwidth of the video
- Is uploading each quality and retrieving as list of URL and parse it in the player is the solution for this??????

```
class ChewieDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChewieDemo({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ChewieDemoState();
  }
}

class _ChewieDemoState extends State<ChewieDemo> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController1;
  late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController2;
  ChewieController? _chewieController;
  int? bufferDelay;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializePlayer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController1.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController2.dispose();
    _chewieController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  List<String> srcs = [
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fortfolio-proj.appspot.com/o/cardHolder%2F121387692_619890725372735_3264722844580789277_n.mp4?alt=media&token=e611257b-07b3-4d07-bfc8-30b0d0e0d86c",
    "https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-daytime-city-traffic-aerial-view-56-large.mp4",
    "https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-a-girl-blowing-a-bubble-gum-at-an-amusement-park-1226-large.mp4"
  ];

  Future<void> initializePlayer() async {
    _videoPlayerController1 =
        VideoPlayerController.network(srcs[currPlayIndex]);
    _videoPlayerController2 =
        VideoPlayerController.network(srcs[currPlayIndex]);
    await Future.wait([
      _videoPlayerController1.initialize(),
      _videoPlayerController2.initialize()
    ]);
    _createChewieController();
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _createChewieController() {
    final subtitles = [
      Subtitle(
        index: 0,
        start: Duration.zero,
        end: const Duration(seconds: 10),
        text: const TextSpan(
          children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Checking sub subtitles',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Subtitle(
        index: 0,
        start: const Duration(seconds: 10),
        end: const Duration(seconds: 20),
        // text: 'Whats up? :)',
        text: const TextSpan(
          text: 'Whats up? :)',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ];

    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      showOptions: false,
      allowMuting: true,
      allowPlaybackSpeedChanging: false,
      allowFullScreen: true,
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
      aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController1.value.aspectRatio,
      autoPlay: true,
      progressIndicatorDelay:
          bufferDelay != null ? Duration(milliseconds: bufferDelay!) : null,
      additionalOptions: (context) {
        return <OptionItem>[
          OptionItem(
            onTap: toggleVideo,
            iconData: Icons.live_tv_sharp,
            title: 'Toggle Video Src',
          ),
        ];
      },
      subtitle: Subtitles(subtitles),
      subtitleBuilder: (context, dynamic subtitle) => Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: subtitle is InlineSpan
            ? RichText(
                text: subtitle,
              )
            : Text(
                subtitle.toString(),
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
      ),
      hideControlsTimer: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
  }

  int currPlayIndex = 0;

  Future<void> toggleVideo() async {
    await _videoPlayerController1.pause();
    currPlayIndex += 1;
    if (currPlayIndex >= srcs.length) {
      currPlayIndex = 0;
    }
    await initializePlayer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _chewieController != null &&
            _chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized
        ? Center(
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController1.value.aspectRatio,
              child: Chewie(
                controller: _chewieController!,
              ),
            ),
          )
        : const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
  }
}
```

Expecting to create a quality controller in video player like youtube parsing mp4 video.

Comment: Your 3rd point is the answer. If not what's the point of downloading a 720p video and then convert locally on the user's device and then play when you could simply play the 720p version.

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to create a adaptive bitrate streaming. when the internet is slow it should change video resolution according to it according to it. Is there any way to control it